# Batch Commands to find and Replace string

Tags: cmd

I want batch commands to find and replace string in word file and also renaming that file with same string and that too for a folder.

Multiple files needs to be searched and replaced with string and at the same time file name should be checked also.

Comment: "word file" as in Microsoft Word? No chance to read/change/write such a file with `cmd`. (Also `fart`, as suggested by @Floempi does only work with pure text files without any formatting). (Working with filenames (like renaming) only would be fine though.)

Answer (score 1):

There exists no integrated funtction in batch.
Powershell has such functions, but i would consider using fart.exe, which is easier to use.

Here is the link -> http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/

//EDIT: Looks like i have not recognized the "word file".
If thats the case i don't know any possibility to do this with batch/cmd.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a macro script by Allen Wyatt that can do this.
[Source](https://word.tips.net/T003783_Changing_Information_in_Multiple_Documents.html)

```
Public Sub MassReplace()
    With Application.FileSearch
        .LookIn = "C:\"             ' where to search
        .SearchSubFolders = True    ' search the subfolders
        .FileName = "*.doc"         ' file pattern to match

        ' if more than one match, execute the following code
        If .Execute() > 0 Then
            ' for each file you find, run this loop
            For i = 1 To .FoundFiles.Count
                ' open the file based on its index position
                Documents.Open FileName:=.FoundFiles(i)

                ' search and replace the address
                selection.Find.ClearFormatting
                selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
                With selection.Find
                    .Text = "OldAddress"
                    .MatchCase = True
                    .Replacement.Text = "NewAddress"
                End With
                selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

                ' replace e-mail address
                With selection.Find
                    .Text = "Oldemail"
                    .Replacement.Text = "Newemail"
                End With
                selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

                ' save and close the current document
                ActiveDocument.Close wdSaveChanges
            Next i
        Else
            ' if the system cannot find any files
            ' with the .doc extension
            MsgBox "No files found."
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Change these 3 lines based on your own needs:

```
.LookIn = "C:\"             ' where to search
.SearchSubFolders = True    ' search the subfolders
.FileName = "*.doc"         ' file pattern to match
```

Aside from that, doing this from batch file (specifically because you are talking word documents) is outside of CMD's abilities.